# Can rabbit and cat live together?

Tags: cats, rabbits

I have a free-roaming (no cage, potty-trained) ~5y old pet rabbit. I would love to adopt a cat from the shelter, but I'm worried about them getting along.

My rabbit is very calm and happy bun, he mostly is just lazying around nearby and is very friendly towards people (licks hands, gets in a lap, etc).

My rabbit did not accept a female bunny friend - she was too bossy, and it upset him greatly. However, he gets fine with parents' cats and dogs, when we visit. He lets dogs lick him and prefers to lie nearby. He is scared of oldest cat, but has mutual interest towards the other one. They lie together in bed and my bunny takes initiative - comes to the cat first, sniffs him, etc. Cat is generally just ignoring him. They are always supervised.

I live in a studio apartment and work from home, but I would still be scared to leave them unsupervised at night / when not home. I could lock bunny up in his old hutch, when I'm away (it's forever open, he hangs out in it), but I feel it would be injustice against him, even though he sleeps there most of the time.

My idea would be to call shelter and look for an adult, calm cat, that is not displaying an agression/without hunting experience. I would ask to foster a cat for a few weeks and see how it goes. But I am still not sure it could work out.

I am afraid my bunny can get hurt at some point, without warning.

Is it a bad idea to keep cat and rabbit together? Maybe somebody has experience with this?

Thank you in advance!